# SQL developer devuelve error: ORA-00942 la tabla o vista no existe, no encuentro que está mal

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Error que empieza en la línea: 22 del comando :

```
CREATE TABLE stock (
codtienda               NUMBER(3)          NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT codtie_FK REFERENCES tienda,
codproducto             NUMBER(5)            NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT codpro_FK REFERENCES producto,
unidades                NUMBER(6)            NOT NULL      CHECK(unidades>=0),
CONSTRAINT sto_PK PRIMARY KEY (codtienda, codproducto)
 )
Informe de error -
ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Este es el error que me devuelve el SQL developer al crear una tabla. Si alguien ve el fallo le estaría agradecido.

Comment: Saludos. Al momento de ejecutarse el `CREATE TABLE` al menos una de las tablas (`tienda` y/o `producto`) no existe o tienes mal el nombre de alguna. *No se bien si aplique, pero quizás el S.O. donde lo tienes diferencie entre mayúsculas/minúsculas donde este el ORACLE sea parte del detalle*.

Comment: HOla Roberto, si creo que tienes razón. He ejecutado todo el script a la vez y me ha dado el error. Pero cuando he ejecutado el script para cada tabla entonces no ha habido problema. Muchas gracias